# What should I do to create a Android Build for React Native CLI App?

Tags: react-native

```
[![I am trying to build APK but I am getting this error.][1]][1]
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I am using React Native CLI and trying to build APK But I failed
Please suggest me more ideas to do this

[image]

Comment: how have you installed the react native application for your mobile?

Comment: This project is successfully running but the problem is only in build creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says the cli is missing. you need to run `npm install @react-native-community/cli` in your project root.